# Problem with running a .sh script in remote location

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a code of python in lets say test.py. I need to run it using Slurm in a remote location. Thats why I am trying to make a .sh file.

In Putty, I am doing these:

```
touch main.sh
echo #!/bin/bash > main.sh
....
echo #SBATCH --gres=gpu:1 >> main.sh
....
echo python3 train.py >> main.sh
```

Then I make it executable with

```
chmod u+x main.sh
```

And I try to run it with

```
bash main.sh
```

But I am getting this error:

```
sbatch: error: This does not look like a batch script.  The first
sbatch: error: line must start with #! followed by the path to an interpreter.
sbatch: error: For instance: #!/bin/sh
```

As I try to check

```
file main.sh
```

I am getting

```
main.sh: ASCII text
```

I am a novice in bash. So I cant understand what the issue is. Can someone help?

Comment: `#` is the shell comment marker, so the command `echo #!/bin/bash > main.sh` is treated as `echo` with the comment `#!/bin/bash > main.sh`... and of course the comment part is ignored. So you need to quote or escape the `#`. Depending on what shell you're using and what mode it's in, `!` may also be a special character (even in double-quotes!). So it's safest to just single-quote the entire string.

Comment: @KhabbabZakaria: Depending on how you configure your bash, `echo #!/bin/bash` will write, when invoked on the command line, _#!/bin/bash_ to stdout, while when invoked in a script (or configured differently), the same statement will just output a newline character. Google for _interactive comments_ to get more insight in this thema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that I used single quotes

```
touch main.sh
echo '#!/bin/bash' > main.sh
echo '#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1' >> main.sh
echo 'python3 --version' >> main.sh

echo 'python3 /home/Desktop/train.py' >> main.sh
```

If train.py is in another directory, you will have to indicate the location